# Two similar methods to re-create objects and emit events

Tags: java, event-handling

I have these two methods basically doing the same thing:

```
private void recreateBlocksIfNeeded() throws WplexError
{
    if (this.blocksToRemove == null || this.blocksToRemove.isEmpty())
        return;


    final List<BlockVO> blocksToCreate = new ArrayList<BlockVO>();
    for (final BlockDeletionStruct struct : this.blocksToRemove)
        blocksToCreate.add(struct.getBlock());
    this.cacheFacade.addBlocks(this.schedule, blocksToCreate, this.blockRules);

    for (final BlockVO block : blocksToCreate)
    {
        for (final ScheduleTripVO scheduleTrip : block.getScheduleTrips())
            AsynchronousEventRunner.publish(scheduleTrip, IEventOperationKind.OBJECT_CREATED);
        AsynchronousEventRunner.publish(block, IEventOperationKind.OBJECT_CREATED);

        this.removeInterfaceEvent(this.interfaceEvents, block, IEventOperationKind.OBJECT_DELETED);
        this.removeInterfaceEvent(this.interfaceEventsPostActions, block, IEventOperationKind.OBJECT_DELETED);
    }
}



private void recreateCrewMembersIfNeeded() throws WplexError
{
    if (this.crewMembersToRemove == null || this.crewMembersToRemove.isEmpty())
        return;

    this.cacheFacade.addCrewMembers(this.schedule, new ArrayList<>(this.crewMembersToRemove), this.crewMemberRules);

    for (final CrewMemberVO crewMember : this.crewMembersToRemove)
    {
        for (final ScheduleTripVO scheduleTrip : crewMember.getScheduleTrips())
            AsynchronousEventRunner.publish(scheduleTrip, IEventOperationKind.OBJECT_CREATED);
        AsynchronousEventRunner.publish(crewMember, IEventOperationKind.OBJECT_CREATED);

        this.removeInterfaceEvent(this.interfaceEvents, crewMember, IEventOperationKind.OBJECT_DELETED);
        this.removeInterfaceEvent(this.interfaceEventsPostActions, crewMember, IEventOperationKind.OBJECT_DELETED);
    }
}
```

And I was wondering if there was a way to create a new more abstract or generic method so I don't have two methods doing basically the same thing, the problem is both BlockVO and CrewMemberVO are child of ValueObject.java with a few common attributes between them, but the method getScheduleTrips() is not in ValueObject, it's in another interfaces called IBlock and ICrewMember.

If not the whole method just the 'for' block at the end.